# swift subclassing NSUserDefaults

Tags: swift, subclass, nsuserdefaults

I have this application which has a couple of properties that I want to store in the NSUserDefaults. I have actually used it the old-school-good-way just referring to the `NSUserDefaults.standardDefaults()` and setting and getting properties.

I recently come up with an idea to actually subclass the NSUserDefaults so I can create there my own methods and don't have to write those extra lines of code all the time.

the code looks something like this:

```
class BRUserDefaults: NSUserDefaults {

    static let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

    static func isFirstRun() -> Bool{
        var wasFirstRun = defaults.boolForKey(GlobalConstants.userDefaults.wasFirstRun)

        return !wasFirstRun
    }

    static func setIsFirstRun(){
        defaults.setBool(true, forKey: GlobalConstants.userDefaults.wasFirstRun)
        defaults.synchronize()
    }
}
```

Is this a good approach?

Thanks a lot

Comment: The syntax looks good, but there is no benefit from subclassing NSUserDefaults. You are in fact creating a normal NSUserDefaults class in your own class. You could also create an extension instead of a subclass if you want to add extra features to the NSUserDefaults class.https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Extensions.html